# How can I make sure the view is rendered only when the type of DataContext matches my data template's target type?

Tags: .net, wpf, vb.net, data-binding, mvvm

```
<ItemsControl DockPanel.Dock="Top" ItemsSource="{Binding Path={x:Static vmc:clsPersonViewModel.ChildrenPath}, Mode=OneWay}">
   <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
      <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vmc:clsPersonViewModel}">
         <TextBlock    Text="{Binding Path={x:Static vmc:clsPersonViewModel.TrimPath}}"
                  Height="20"
                  Margin="2">
         </TextBlock>
      </DataTemplate>
   </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

In the code above, if there are no children (the ChildrenPath property returns NULL), nothing is rendered in the view.  In the code below, when ChildrenDataSetPath is NULL the XamDataGrid still gets rendered.  How do I achieve the same for a single object (as opposed to a collection) as the datacontext?

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vmb:clsPersonViewModel}">
   <igDP:XamDataGrid DataSource="{Binding Path={x:Static vmb:clsPersonViewModel.ChildrenDataSetPath}}">
   </igDP:XamDataGrid>
</DataTemplate>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally achieved this by using ContentControl.  I mapped my DataContext to Content property of ContentControl and then added Datat Template for the view in resources.  When the datacontext is not of type clsPersonViewModel, it does not show the ucPersonView.

```
<ContentControl Content="{Binding ElementName=_RightSidePanel, Path=DataContext}" >
<ContentControl.Resources>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vmb:clsPersonViewModel}">
        <igDP:ucPersonView />               
    </DataTemplate>
</ContentControl.Resources>
</ContentControl>
```

Answer (score 0):

In the second case, you're applying the DataTemplate to a clsPersonViewModel singleton, and then you're saying that, no matter what, there's a grid in there.  Then in the grid you're binding the DataSource.  As long as you're applying the DataTemplate to a singleton that's always there, you should be fine.

For instance, suppose the PersonViewModel exposed a `Parent` property.  You could do this:

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vmb:clsPersonViewModel}">
    <igDP:ParentView DataContext="{Binding Path={x:Static vmb:clsPersonViewModel.Parent}}">
    </igDP:ParentView>
</DataTemplate>
```

Comment: My DataContext is set to a base ViewModel on the outer control and I'm trying to render different views based on what type of ViewModel it is. When my DataContext ViewModel is of type clsPersonViewModel, I want to show a grid but I don't want the grid control to render at all if it's not of clsPersonViewModel type.